# insert array data to textbox

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to insert array data in textbox?

This is my array:

```
[MTS] => Array
(
    [103] => Array
        (
            [0] => MTS
            [1] => Lorvia  Christine
            [2] => 103
            [3] => 6/16/2014 9:31
        )
)

[SSS] => Array
(
    [104] => Array
        (
            [0] => SSS
            [1] => Jannah Curtis
            [2] => 104
            [3] => 6/28/2014 14:29 
        )
)

[ITM] => Array
(
    [105] => Array
        (
            [0] => ITM
            [1] => Sassy Mica
            [2] => 105
            [3] => 6/18/2014 9:12
        )
)
```

And I want to make my form like this:

[image]

And if this way is impossible can someone recommend me an another way to output it on textbox.

Comment: Can you not just echo the values into the HTML element? I don't really understand the issue here. Could you please explain what problem you are facing? Perhaps include some attempts that you have made with PHP?

Comment: Yes - you have already made that statement. We will need more context to understand what you are trying to do. Is this array being retrieved with an AJAX request? Is the data already on the server before the page is sent to the user?

Comment: I already tried to echo the every rows printed in textboxes but the output is not appearing. My only problem is to submit all array data into textboxes.

Comment: Please with us share the attempts you have made - this is the best way for us to understand.

Comment: To answer your questions in order _And if this way is impossible_ it is - people seem to do it all the time. I've also done it. _can someone recommend me an another way to output it on textbox._ What other way? As in, different to what - I don't see what have you tried and is not working. When should this be done - on page load, on page construction, during the interaction with the page? Not knowing this nor knowing what didn't work, I'm afraid I can't recommend anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$arrayname['arraykey']?>" />
```

And that's all you need to do.